# Understanding design patterns and struggling to write code for it

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

I'm trying to understand design patterns and I want to implement the best way into my project. I have been reading about it last two days and I understand that singleton pattern is not good unless you want to use it for database. And I wrote the bellow code which is I believe factory pattern. But I don't understand why do I need to use interface? Is there anything wrong with my code? Could you give me any example? My goal is that I want send mail without writing settings for phpmailer every time I need to send mail. Or for any other library I use.

Thanks.

this is my folder structure..

```
-lib
---Config.php (configuration class)
---Mail.php
-logs
-models
---Users.php
-public (web root)
---index.php (get routers)
-routers
---users.router.php
-templates
---users.html.twig
-vendor
---slim
---phpmailer
.composer.json
config.php
```

Mail.php

```
class Mail {
    protected $mail;

    public function __construct(PHPMailer $mail) {
        $this->mail = $mail;
        $this->mail->isHTML(Config::read('mail.isHtml'));
        $this->mail->setFrom(Config::read('mail.fromEmail'), Config::read('mail.fromName'));
    }

    public function sendMail ( $to, $subject, $body, $plainText ) {
        $this->mail->addAddress($to);
        $this->mail->Subject = $subject;
        $this->mail->Body = $body;
        $this->mail->AltBody = $plainText;

        $this->mail->send();
    }
}
```

user.router.php

```
$app->get( '/test', function () use ( $app ) {

    $app->log->info("test '/test' route");

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $test = new lib\Mail($mail);

    $test->sendMail('test@domain.com', 'Subject', '<html>Hello username</html>', 'Hello username' );


    var_dump($test);
});
```

config.php

```
Config::write('mail.fromEmail', 'no_reply@domain.dev');
Config::write('mail.fromName', 'Domain LTD');
Config::write('mail.isHtml', true);
```

Comment: Design patterns are generally reusable *solutions* to commonly occurring *problems*. It's best that you understand the problems FIRST before you try to apply a solution. Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

**First:** I can't see any factory pattern in your code.

**Second:**
The purpose of using a factory pattern is to get an instance of a class without exactly knowing wich implementation of the class you get. Lets say you have 2 classes, A and B `

```
class MailerHTML {}

class MailerText {}
```

Now you could implement a factory that decides which mailer you want to use.

```
class MailerFactory 
{
   public function getMailer($supportsHTML)
   {
      if ($supportsHTML) {
          return new MailerHTML();
      } else { 
          return new MailerText();
      }
   }
}
```

Now you can get al Mailer form you MailerFactory without knowing what kind of mail will be send, but you don't know what method signature your mailer object has, too. 
To fix this issue, you usually implement an interface to the mailer classes, that in your case, abstracts the `sendMail` method

```
interface MailerInterface 
{
    public function sendMail($to, $subject, $body, $plainText);
}

class MailerHTML implements MailerInterface 
{
    public function sendMail($to, $subject, $body, $plainText) { ... }
}

class MailerText implements MailerInterface {}
{
    public function sendMail($to, $subject, $body, $plainText) { ... }
}
```

Comment: This is not "real" factory pattern. It's sometimes called "simple factory" but many don't consider it a pattern at all. Notice how for every new type of `Mailer` you'd need to modify the `getMailer` method, which violates open/closed principle.

Comment: @lafor hi, what is the best way dealing with external libraries like phpmailer then? could you please give an example or a method for me to implement it into my code? thanks.

Comment: @lafor A factory basically just means that you use a separate class / method to create an object instead of directly calling the constructor of the class that you want to instantiate (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) But to answer the question, i don't see any problem in erdems implementation depends on your needs, i tried to keep my example as simple as possible.  don't see any problem in you implementation so far, just the term factory pattern was wrong ;)